# Log4Net not creating .txt file?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, configuration, log4net

This is my first attempt at logging, and I have researched similar questions, but cant seem to figure out my situation, probably because I am not getting any errors to go off of.

I am trying to use Log4Net to simply create a .txt file. I do not have a web.config or app.config, so I created my own config file to setup Log4Net(Through research, I found that I should be able to do this). The config file is below:

Log4Net.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,  log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\myFolder\TestLog.txt" />//******Nothing Is Being Created Here****
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

In my AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile =
            "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

And the call to the logger

```
....
private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("ExportLogger");
....
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();//I know this shouldnt be done here, just testing
 logger.Debug("Successfully logged something");
```

The above code all runs without error, so I am not sure where my mistake is. I suspect I have the configuration setup incorrectly. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and why there is no creation of the .txt file?

Comment: check write access rights of application pool user to your folder 'C:\myFolder'

Comment: Assuming it isn't just permissions - as you're using a standalone log4net config file, you should probably remove the `<configuration>` and `<configSections>` elements, as they are only applicable to app/web.config files. Also use the overload of `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()` that lets you pass in that file. You can check `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured` to see if the configuration has been loaded. If it still doesn't work, [add a trace listener to the debug output](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/)

Comment: Did you make sure the log4net.dll is available in the bin directory?

Comment: @NickProzee Yes the dll is there

Answer (score 0):

The error in your attribute:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile =
        "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

You define the configuration file, but you are using the app.config for the configuration.

This will fix your problem:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```